# Can I robustly construct a tree with multiple known types and known maximum depth at compile time with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, tree

I got it into my head fairly recently that I would attempt to create a tree of 'lists'. That is, a tree where each level is a list, so it's not a binary tree. Furthermore, I wanted to try to make each level of the tree a different type, specifically four different types - one for each level. Lastly, I intended to see if I could, at compile-time, fix the height of the tree by employing three different templates.

tree_middle, for the the intermediate levels of the tree,

```
template<typename a, typename b, typename c>
struct tree_middle
{
    tree_middle *m_prev;
    tree_middle *m_next;

    a *m_upper;

    b *m_node;

    c *m_lower;
};
```

tree_bottom, for the bottom of the tree,

```
template<typename a, typename b>
struct tree_bottom
{
    tree_bottom *m_prev;
    tree_bottom *m_next;

    a *m_upper;

    b *m_node;
};
```

and tree_top for the top of the tree.

```
template<typename a, typename b>
struct tree_top
{
    tree_top *m_prev;
    tree_top *m_next;

    a *m_node;

    b *m_lower;
};
```

After toying around with different implementations, I basically resorted to some workarounds wherein I had a type that denoted the penultimate tree level:

```
template<typename a, typename b, typename c>
struct tree_prebottom
{
    tree_prebottom *m_prev;
    tree_prebottom *m_next;

    a *m_upper;

    b *m_node;

    tree_bottom<tree_prebottom, c> *m_lower;
};
```

By defining yet another template, I could create a tree that was fixed at three levels with three different types. Notice that three_tree functions as tree_top in this template. This is close to what I wanted.

```
template<typename a, typename b, typename c>
struct three_tree
{
    three_tree *m_prev;
    three_tree *m_next;

    a *m_node;

    tree_prebottom<three_tree, b, c> *m_lower;
};
```

Taking that one step further, I ended up with a template that could generate the type that I was looking for, the four_tree. But notice this ludicrous display going on here? I am writing 'generic' code in a rather loose sense here, agreed? The only thing generic about it at are the consumed types, really. Note: This part was edited when I noticed that the four_tree had no proper link back to the top level.)

```
template<typename a, typename b, typename c, typename d>
struct tree_threebottom
{
    tree_threebottom *m_prev;
    tree_threebottom *m_next;

    a *m_upper;

    b *m_node;

    tree_prebottom<tree_threebottom, c, d> *m_lower;
};

template<typename a, typename b, typename c, typename d>
struct four_tree
{
    four_tree *m_prev;
    four_tree *m_next;

    a *m_node;

    tree_threebottom<four_tree, b, c, d> *m_lower;
};
```

The question is, is there a better and more elegant way to do this? The roadblock I ran into when trying to do the original implementation was that when you're specifying type inputs for a template, you can't pass the type you're 'in' at the moment as a parameter. Thus, my approach suffered from never being able to create a complete type due to a sort of cyclic dependency. Even the two level tree suffers from this if you just limit yourself to tree_top and tree_bottom:

```
template<typename a, typename b>
struct tree_bottom
{
    tree_bottom *m_prev;
    tree_bottom *m_next;

    a *m_upper;

    b *m_node;
};

template<typename a, typename b>
struct tree_top
{
    tree_top *m_prev;
    tree_top *m_next;

    a *m_node;

    b *m_lower;
};
```

The templates are fine on their own, until you try to define an actual type with them. For example

```
typedef tree_top< int, tree_bottom<tree_top<int, tree_bottom< /*see the problem?*/, short> > int_short_tree;
```

Note that the tree implementation is pretty simplistic, but I was looking to emulate a tree template I found here: http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/coretree2/index.html I have also seen similar implementations elsewhere, but they all assume a tree composed of a single type. The natural response to this might be, "Well why not use polymorphism?". I have seen that technique in action as well, such as in the LLVM project, and while I don't have any problem with it, I was curious to know if I could statically (at compile time) construct a type that subverts the need for polymorphism, since in my particular case I knew all of the types involved, and I knew that the tree had a fixed height (four).

I also contemplated using inheritance combined with templates to achieve a more robust solution, but the solution has eluded me, if it exists. It seems to me that I could manually create types of this sort, including trees with 5 levels or more. Am I hitting a limitation of the template system here, or just not being clever enough?

Comment: This might be better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: [stlplus](http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/) can be useful.

Comment: I think what you're trying to create is something like a doubly-linked type list, and AFAIK, that's impossible. You can create a singly-linked type list, where each type points to the next type. In your tree, that would be each level/node knows the type of its child node/type but NOT the type of its parent. But of course, you can create doubly-linked lists at run-time, so you had to use type of `m_upper` a pointer to a type `X` that does not include its own base classes as template arguments. From this type `X`, derive the actual node type and use polymorphism.

Comment: @PeterWood I've no problem with that if that's the appropriate location for this sort of question.

Comment: @DyP Yes, creating trees in this way when you only need one direction of linking is substantially easier, but navigating a tree in only one direction kind of defeats the point a bit. If only there were a way to partially construct a type and then finish it in a later step... Also what you say isn't entirely true. I can achieve what I want by using the tree_middle template listed above, but using void to endcap the four level tree. Example : typedef tree_middle<void, char, tree_middle<char, short, tree_middle<short, int, tree_middle<int, long, void> > > > char_short_int_long_tree;

Comment: @DyP (continued) It's just that this design has extraneous parts, and I've heard over and over again this is bad design. On the other hand, the other design has extraneous parts in the form of a proliferation of templates in order to satisfy the requirements of the target type structure.

Comment: "navigating a tree in only one direction" that's not what I meant. Rather, by using a singly-linked type list you can only navigate the _types_ of the tree in one direction at compile-time. Of course, you can navigate through the tree in both directions at run-time, using pointer types in one direction (e.g. parent) that don't include the child types as template arguments. E.g. `tree_node < tree_node < tree_node < int > > >` for some class template `tree_node < TChild >`. I don't quite understand the template arguments in your example though, `char* m_upper;` - not `tree_middle<..>* m_upper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have an idea of what you want and how you could achieve it. It doesn't fit well the SO format, though, I think.

First, the syntax to create & use the tree:

```
int main()
{
    // We want a tree with 4 levels.
    // The node type of the 0th level should be `int`,
    // of the 1st level `double` and so on.
    // (0th level = tree root)
    // And we initialize the root node with the `int` 42.
    auto my_tree = make_tree_root < int, double, char, float, int > (42);

    // add children and navigate through the tree
    my_tree.add_child(1.23);
    my_tree.add_child(4.56);
    my_tree.get_child(1).add_child('x');
    my_tree.get_child(1).get_child(0).add_child(1.2f);

    my_tree.print();
}
```

And now the mess in the background. Note that it is rather a proof-of-concept, it has so many flaws that having no comments may be a bless. Especially the multiple inheritance used to reduce code copying creates more problems than it solves.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>    
#include <vector>

template < typename... TP >
struct type_vector
{
private:
    template < std::size_t t_count, typename TT, typename... TTP >
    struct access_elem { using value = typename access_elem < t_count-1, TTP... > :: value; }; 
        template < typename TT, typename... TTP >
        struct access_elem < 0, TT, TTP... > { using value = TT; };

public:
    template < std::size_t t_id >
    using elem = typename access_elem < t_id, TP... > :: value;
};


template < typename, std::size_t, std::size_t >
struct tree_node;

template < typename T_type_vector, std::size_t t_level, std::size_t t_maxLevel >
struct tree_all_base
{
    using node = typename T_type_vector::template elem < t_level >;

protected:
    node m_node;

public:
    explicit tree_all_base(node p) : m_node(p) {}

    void change_node(node);
    node get_node() const { return m_node; }

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "node: " << m_node << std::endl;
    }
};

template < typename T_type_vector, std::size_t t_level, std::size_t t_maxLevel >
struct tree_down_base
{
    using child = tree_node < T_type_vector, t_level+1, t_maxLevel >;

private:
    std::vector<child> m_children;

public:
    void add_child(typename child::node p)
    {
        using derived_type = tree_node < T_type_vector, t_level, t_maxLevel >;
        m_children.push_back( child{p, static_cast<derived_type*>(this)} );
    } 
    child const& get_child(std::size_t id) const { return m_children.at(id); }
    child& get_child(std::size_t id) { return m_children.at(id); }
    // further methods like `remove_child` etc

protected:
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "children: ";
        for(child const& c : m_children)
        {
            std::cout << c.get_node() << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(child const& c : m_children)
        {
            c.print();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

template < typename T_type_vector, std::size_t t_level, std::size_t t_maxLevel >
struct tree_up_base
    : public tree_all_base < T_type_vector, t_level, t_maxLevel >
{
    using tree_all_base_ = tree_all_base<T_type_vector,t_level,t_maxLevel>;
    using parent = tree_node < T_type_vector, t_level-1, t_maxLevel >;
    using node = typename tree_all_base_::node;

protected:
    parent* m_parent;

    tree_up_base(node p_node, parent* p)
        : tree_all_base_(p_node), m_parent(p)
    {}
};


template < typename T_type_vector, std::size_t t_level, std::size_t t_maxLevel >
struct tree_node
    : public tree_up_base  <T_type_vector, t_level, t_maxLevel>
    , public tree_down_base<T_type_vector, t_level, t_maxLevel>
{
    using node = typename tree_all_base<T_type_vector,t_level,t_maxLevel>::node;
private:
    /* inherit ctor....*/
    using tree_up_base_ = tree_up_base<T_type_vector,t_level,t_maxLevel>;
    using tree_down_base_ = tree_down_base<T_type_vector,t_level,t_maxLevel>;
    using tree_node_parent = tree_node<T_type_vector,t_level-1,t_maxLevel>;

    friend struct tree_down_base < T_type_vector, t_level-1, t_maxLevel >;
    tree_node(node p, tree_node_parent* pb) : tree_up_base_(p, pb) {}

public:
    void print() const
    {
        tree_up_base_::print();
        tree_down_base_::print();
    }
};
    // tree root specialization
    template < typename T_type_vector, std::size_t t_maxLevel >
    struct tree_node < T_type_vector, 0, t_maxLevel >
        : public tree_all_base <T_type_vector, 0, t_maxLevel>
        , public tree_down_base<T_type_vector, 0, t_maxLevel>
    {
    public:
        /* inherit ctor..... */
        using tree_all_base_ = tree_all_base<T_type_vector,0,t_maxLevel>;
        using tree_down_base_ = tree_down_base<T_type_vector,0,t_maxLevel>;
        using node = typename tree_all_base_ :: node;
        tree_node(node p) : tree_all_base_(p) {}

    public:
        void print() const
        {
            tree_all_base_::print();
            tree_down_base_::print();
        }
    };

    // tree leaf specialization
    template < typename T_type_vector, std::size_t t_maxLevel >
    struct tree_node < T_type_vector, t_maxLevel, t_maxLevel >
        : public tree_up_base <T_type_vector, t_maxLevel, t_maxLevel>
    {
    private:
        /* inherit ctor.... */
        using tree_up_base_ = tree_up_base<T_type_vector,t_maxLevel,t_maxLevel>;
        using node = typename tree_up_base_ :: node;
        using tree_node_parent = tree_node<T_type_vector,t_maxLevel-1,t_maxLevel>;

        friend struct tree_down_base < T_type_vector, t_maxLevel-1, t_maxLevel >;
        tree_node(node p, tree_node_parent* pb) : tree_up_base_(p, pb) {}
    };

template < typename... TP >
tree_node < type_vector<TP...>, 0, sizeof...(TP)-1 >
make_tree_root(typename type_vector<TP...>::template elem<0> node)
{ return {node}; }
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to review and accept this answer, I needed to muster the appropriate spare time and braincells, as it at first appeared somewhat daunting. This is strikingly similar to what I had in mind when I was talking about using inheritance originally, I just was at a loss as to how to do that. It seems this question makes for a good opportunity to showcase of some of the C++11 language additions in your answer. I'm left wondering whether you can even solve this without C++11, actually. I really appreciate the elegance and attention to detail of this answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @mathonnapkins IIRC, the only unique C++11 features I used are variadic templates, those can be "emulated" using long fixed-size type lists with default "sentinel" arguments (see e.g. boost's metaprogramming libraries). E.g. `template < class T0, class T1 = sentinel, class T3 = sentinel /*and so on*/ > struct type_vector;`

Comment: Well, I don't know if they were essential, but you did use what appeared to me to be 'alias templates' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alias_templates). I liked the exposition of c++11 features regardless, though. =).

Comment: @mathonnapkins True, but these are only syntactical sugar (removing the `::value` and possibly the `typename` in some contexts). The other name aliases declared by `using` instead of `typedef` are easier to read IMO.